# Como centralizar um form sem afetar os labels?

Tags: html5, css3

Eu tenho um formulário assim:
[image: formulário]

O `form` está dentro de uma classe chamada `container` que tem os seguintes atributos:
`

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Se eu adicionar um `text-align:center` no container, eu consigo centralizar o form. Porém, quando eu faço isso, os labels que estão em cima dos inputs, ficam centralizados em relação ao input também.

Como posso centralizar o form sem que isso aconteça?

O html do Formulário é esse:

```
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="age">Idade:</label>
      <input type="number" name="age" id="age" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="work-area">Área de atuação:</label>
      <select name="work-area" id="work-area" required>
        <option value="developer">Desenvolvedor</option>
        <option value="infra">Infraestrutura</option>
        <option value="designer">Designer</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="vacation">Férias?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vacation" id="vacation">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="entry-date">Data de entrada:</label>
      <input type="date" required id="entry-date">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Certo, e onde está o HTML desse form? Nós teremos que cria-los para fazermos teste? Leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo adicionado.

Comment: veja se com `width: 50%;` fica certo

Comment: Ele foi um pouco para a direita, mas não centralizou.

Comment: Pelas classes parece que vc está usando Bootstrap confere? Se está qual versão é?

Comment: @hugocsl Não estou. O form-group e container, eu criei.

Comment: Ok jovem é pq as classes tem os mesmo nomes rss. De qq forma já postei um exemplo como resposta que pode te ajudar.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Na verdade a sua solução funcionou. É que eu tinha me atrapalhado com o tamanho dos inputs, pois estou usando porcentagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o recurso flexbox do css3:

```
.container {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center
}
```

Exemplo: 
https://codepen.io/biancassilva/pen/KexbjK

Answer (score 0):

Acho que definindo `margin: 0px auto` num container já resolve.

```css
.container{
  width:400px;
  margin: 0px auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="age">Idade:</label>
      <input type="number" name="age" id="age" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="work-area">Área de atuação:</label>
      <select name="work-area" id="work-area" required>
        <option value="developer">Desenvolvedor</option>
        <option value="infra">Infraestrutura</option>
        <option value="designer">Designer</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="vacation">Férias?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vacation" id="vacation">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="entry-date">Data de entrada:</label>
      <input type="date" required id="entry-date">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```